# L2E many to many query

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I have four tables:

```
Users                  PrivilegeGroups        rdPrivileges        LinkPrivilege
-----------            ----------------       ---------------     ---------------
userId(pk)             privilegeGroupId(pk)   privilegeId(pk)     privilegeId(pk, fk)
privilegeGroupId(fk)   name                   code                privilegeGroupId(pk, fk)
```

L2E will not create `LinkPrivilege` entity for me. So we only have `Users`, `PrivilegeGroups` and `rdPrivileges` entities. `PrivilegeGroups` and `rdPrivileges` are many to many relationship.

What I need to do is retrieve all `code` from `rdPrivileges` table based on a passed in userId. How can I do it?

```
EDIT
```

credite to juharr, the working code:

```
var codes = from u in db.Users
          from pg in db.PrivilegeGroups
          from p in pg.rdPrivileges
          where u.UserId == passedInUserId
             && u.PrivilegeGroups.PrivilegeGroupId == pg.PrivilegeGroupId
          select p.Code;
```

Comment: Actually this is linq-to-sql, not linq-to-entities.

Comment: @juharr: Actually it is not. This is Entity Framework, and thus linq-to-entities. You're probably confused with linq-to-objects?

Comment: @Sander I hate terminology sometimes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think something like this would work.

```
var codes = from u in Users
            from pg in u.PrivilegeGroups
            from p in pg.rdPrivileges
            where u.userId == "SomeUserID"
            select p.code;
```